# Association between a custom list and an external list

Tags: bcs, lookup-column, external-list

I have a very basic question.

I have a Custom List and I'd like to add a lookup column from an External List based on a WCF Service. Is it possible?

E.g. I have employers in a custom list. I'd like to associate them whit their company, but the company id and name comes from an External List.

Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can create custom list with lookup column from external list
Regards.

Comment: How can I do that? When I create a Lookup column, the SP Design shows a Column editor with a “list or document library” list that I can choose the Custom List which I will create an association. My external lists don’t appear is this list of lists and document. Why? There’s another way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: It is a very strange behavior. I was only able to do that directly through Sharepoint's front-end in web browser. I was used to create my columns using Sharepoint Design, but it doesn’t allow me to create columns associated with external data.